# reassigning a pointer in csharp

Tags: c#, pointers, fixed, unsafe

I am having an issue trying to port the following code from C to C#. not having much success with using the fixed keyword and a ptr that gets reassigned. Could someone tell me how to represent the following code in c#?

```
        p = &table[(i = start[k]) >> m];
        i <<= tablebits;
        n = k - tablebits;
    /* make tree (n length) */
        while (--n >= 0) {
            if (*p == 0) {
                right[avail] = left[avail] = 0;
                *p = avail++;
            }
            if (i & 0x8000) p = &right[*p];
            else            p = &left[*p];
            i <<= 1;
        }
        *p = j;
```

Comment: This is the sort of code that reminds me why I now use C#. :) The entire way of dealing with this kind of problem is different in C#. You can't port this kind of C to C# by direct translation. It is better to step back and look at the problem being solved, and approach it from a C# perspective.

Comment: understandable, but not very helpful in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here goes using no pointers (C# safe)...

```
var[] curtable = table;
i = start[k];
int idx = i >> m;

i <<= tablebits;
n = k - tablebits;

/* make tree (n length) */
while (--n >= 0) 
{
    if (curtable[idx] == 0) 
    {
        right[avail] = left[avail] = 0;
        curtable[idx] = avail++;
    }
    if (i & 0x8000) 
    {
          idx = curtable[idx];
          curtable = right;
    }
    else  
    {
          idx = curtable[idx];
          curtable = left;
     }
    i <<= 1;
}
curtable[idx] = j;
```

Comment: very nice translation indeed

Comment: This answer is a lot more helpful than my initial comment, and very nicely done too!

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem.. by the end of this sequence, you are assigning j to an element of table. but in the original code, j will be assigned to an element of table, right, or left, not just table. Thus the ptr is changed to the element of the appropriate table.

Comment: or rather, the ptr is set to an element of either the left or right table. then the value of j is placed in that element.

Comment: Looks like I was able to resolve the issue by using fixed pointers for each of the tables, then a changable ptr that I can assign the appropriate fixed pointer to. compiles fine and code appears to operate with the same result as the c code.

Comment: fixed(ushort* p = &table[(i = start[k]) >> m])
    {
        ushort* p4 = p;
        i <<= tablebits;
        n = k - tablebits;
        /* make tree (n length) */
        while (--n >= 0)
        {
            if (*p == 0)
            {
                right[avail] = left[avail] = 0;
                *p = (ushort)avail++;
            }
            if ((i & 0x8000) > 0) fixed(ushort* p2 = &right[*p4]) {p4 = p2;}
            else fixed (ushort* p3 = &left[*p4]) { p4 = p3; }
            i <<= 1;
        }
        *p4 = (ushort)j;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was able to resolve the issue by using fixed pointers for each of the tables, then a changable ptr that I can assign the appropriate fixed pointer to. compiles fine and code appears to operate with the same result as the c code.

```
    fixed(ushort* p = &table[(i = start[k]) >> m])
    {
        ushort* p4 = p;
        i <<= tablebits;
        n = k - tablebits;
        /* make tree (n length) */
        while (--n >= 0)
        {
            if (*p == 0)
            {
                right[avail] = left[avail] = 0;
                *p = (ushort)avail++;
            }
            if ((i & 0x8000) > 0) fixed(ushort* p2 = &right[*p4]) {p4 = p2;}
            else fixed (ushort* p3 = &left[*p4]) { p4 = p3; }
            i <<= 1;
        }
        *p4 = (ushort)j;
    }
```